# Creating Branches within Git with just new files and modifications

Tags: git, github

I have cloned master repo from github to my local. I have created my feature branch and made some modifications. Now my Feature branch contains master plus my changes. Is there a way to branch out with just the files I have updated and/or created without having all the contents from master? Example (Master = 5 original files) (Feature = 4 original files, plus 1 modification, and 2 new files) What is a way to create a branch that contains (1 modification and 2 new files)?

Comment: Why do you want this? It could be done, but what is the purpose of _storing_ the changes only in a separate _branch_? git provides the `diff` whenever it is necessary to show what has changed, a branch is not needed for this. I'm curious about the use case.

Comment: Hello Mehdi, Alot of cloud based development doesn't require the entire contents of the branch you branch off of. So builds and integration can happen on a baseline branch and not a developer's own branch. So I need developer's own branch as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that *might* achieve what you're looking for.

1. `git stash`
   Stash your pending changes.
2. `git checkout -b new-branch`
   Switch to a new branch.
3. `rm -r *` Delete all files in directory. Might require additional commands to delete sub-directories and their contents.
4. `git stash apply` Reapply pending changes.

Note this will register the deletion of the unchanged files as a pending change. I don't know if you'll be able to branch off of master without git considering the removal/exclusion of the other files as a pending change. I could **definitely** be wrong though.

This question also makes me very curious about your workflow/end goal.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!